# Update spring data JPA entity

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

Good day, please I am updating an entity through a `receiptNumber` to specify if the transaction is successful or failed. whenever I execute my code here is the error I am getting from the postman app

```
"status": 405,
"error": "Method Not Allowed",
```

Any help will be appreciated thank you in advance.

here is my entity

```java
@Document(collection = "PayBillValidate")
public class PayBill {

    @Id
    private String _id;
    private String date;
    private String src;
    private String dest;
    private String url;
    private String status;
    private String processing_time;
    private String httpMethod;
    private String MSISDN;
    private String BillIssuerShortCode;
    private String BillRefNumber;
    private String TransAmount;
    private String InvoiceNumber;
    private String TransDate;

    @Field("ReceiptNumber")
    private String receiptNumber;
    private String KYCInfo;
    private String finalStatus;

  getters, setters...
}
```

here is my repository

```java
public interface PayBillRepository extends MongoRepository<PayBill, String> {
    PayBill findByReceiptNumber (String receiptNumber);
}
```

here is my service

```java
public PayBill updateVCashTopUpStatus(String receiptNumber){
    PayBill payBill = payBillRepository.findByReceiptNumber(receiptNumber);
    payBill.setFinalStatus("Success");
    return payBill;
}
```

here is my controller

```java
@PutMapping("/payBill{receiptNumber}")
public PayBill updateVCashTopUp(@PathVariable String receiptNumber){
  return dataLogService.updateVCashTopUpStatus(receiptNumber);
}
```

Comment: When calling your api from postman which method are you setting? is it put or get?

Comment: Your API defines the call as having a `PUT` method. I suspect that your Postman client's http method is set to `GET` (the default value when creating a new request). Switch that over to `PUT` and the problem should go away.

Comment: please the method is set to PUT

Comment: Take a screen shot of your Postman request, or copy the curl command,

Comment: We need to know how you are calling your API in Postman, so please share this information. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Comb through your website’s code to find bugs.
   If there’s a mistake in your website’s code, your web server might not be able to correctly answer requests from a content delivery network. Comb through your code to find bugs or copy your code into a development machine. It’ll perform a thorough debug process that will simulate the exact situation your 405 Method Not Allowed Error occurred in and allow you to see the exact moment where things went wrong.
2. Sift through your server-side logs.
   There are two types of server-side logs -- applications logs and server logs. Application logs recount your website’s entire history, like the web pages requested by visitors and which servers it connected to. Server logs provide information about the hardware running your server, revealing details about its health and status. Sift through both types of server-side logs to uncover any alarming information about your server or website.
3. Check your server configuration files.
   The last way to find out what’s causing your 405 Method Not Allowed Error is by taking a look at your web server’s configuration files. You can usually find instructions for solving unintentional redirects there.